# How to right to left bootstrap 4 columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, right-to-left

I copied form example of Bootstrap 4, But I can't change its direction from right to left.

```
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
<style>…</style>
.col-md-3 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

After removing `flex styles`, `right float` style can change it to `rtl` direction. But is there another way to change its direction without ignoring flex styles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was not enough familiar with flex style. After reading the whole flex styles, I found this way:

```
.row {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

I think this is the right way to change the direction.